# JAX-RS Web Service to receive an email with atttachments

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, jax-rs, email-attachments

I am creating a JAX-RS Web Service which can receive emails and forward the data to client. 
Currently I can work with simple emails. But I have no idea about how to implement this for emails with attachments. 
I know it should be done in 2 steps.

1. My JAX-RS downloads the attachments from the mail server to my server.
2. Send these files to the client.

Any suggestions implementing this.

Comment: For point 1. You can have a look at here http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#GettingAttachments

Comment: @Maxx - yeah i figured that much! now any suggestions about making the second step work?? I meean send the file to the client of my web service...
(p.s. - I have to assume that my client does not know the complexities working in the background he should have a simple web service interface to work with...)

Comment: @Maxx - I would be fine if I can just give a download link of the attachments to the client..

Comment: yes your service would have to expose a servlet for downloading the attached files ... I already did something similar the only problem had been figuring, from the web service, the full servlet address (host name + port etc.) ... at last I gave up and configured it on a properties file.
I was working with Axis may be JAX-RS offers sone different way to do it ...

Comment: You may have a look at here too ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736973/dynamically-create-image-from-jax-rs-servlet