# Error while getting resources from JAX-RS service

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs

I have simple JAX-RS server application:

```
@GET
@Path("/getImage/{key}")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public final BufferedImage getImageResource(@PathParam("key") String key) {
  final File file = new File(key); // the key will be "cat.jpeg" e.t.c.

  final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(file));

  return image;
}
```

After deploying war file to tomcat server (6.0), i do next:

```
http://localhost:8080/resource-service/getImage/cat.png
```

Problems:

1)On *new File(key)* it'll go to tomcat root directory. I'd like to have something like default root folder for resources inside project directory around classes.

2)Returning BufferedImage doesn't allowed as i understand, i get 500 error message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.awt.image.BufferedImage of media type: image/jpeg
```

I'd appreciate any advice, links.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't mention your JAX-RS provider, but in any case none of them (afaik) provides a MessageBodyWriter out of the box capable of serializing a BufferedImage directly. Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204824/680925) for information on converting the buffered image into a byte array or input stream as an intermediary step before serialization - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204824/680925.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get access to the files in your WAR package you should use [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). First, inject it first into your class as a variable:

```
@Context
ServletContext context;
```

and then find files using:

```
final File file = new File(this.context.getRealPath(key));
```

It's not possible to return a `BufferedImage` (and map it automatically to `image/jpeg`), but in your example you don't need to do it. Just return a JAX-RS response:

```
@GET
@Path("/getImage/{key}")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public final Response get(@PathParam("key") String key) {
    return Response.ok()
        .entity(this.context.getResourceAsStream(key))
        .type("image/jpeg")
        .build();
}
```

Similar question: [Dynamically create image from JAX-RS servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736973/dynamically-create-image-from-jax-rs-servlet)